# Get all members in Sorted Set

Tags: redis

I have a Sorted set and want to get all members of set. How to identify a max/min score for command :

```
zrange key min max
```

?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You're in luck, as [`zrange`](http://redis.io/commands/zrange) does not take scores, but indices. `0` is the first index, and `-1` will be interpreted as the last index:

```
zrange key 0 -1
```

To get a range by score, you would call [`zrangebyscore`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) instead -- where `-inf` and `+inf` can be used to denote negative and positive infinity, respectively, as Didier Spezia notes in his comment:

```
zrangebyscore key -inf +inf
```

Comment: And for zrangebyscore, -inf and +inf can be used for the same purpose.

Comment: Does using `zrange key 0 -1` carry the same I/O concerns that calls like `SMEMBERS` and `KEYS` do? The Redis documentation is pretty explicit in `SMEMBERS` that it can be better to use `SSCAN`, but it doesn't say anything about `ZSCAN` over `ZRANGE ... 0 -1`

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if the results require a cursor, then it's more expensive.

Comment: For a nodejs and ioredis setup with `zrangebyscore`,  both (string) `+inf` or (number) `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` work.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Redis 6.2.0,

To get all the keys and its value together in a single query using the below,

`zrange <KEY> 0 -1 WITHSCORES`

The optional WITHSCORES argument supplements the command's reply with the scores of elements returned. The returned list contains value1,score1,...,valueN,scoreN instead of value1,...,valueN. Client libraries can return a more appropriate data type (suggestion: an array with (value, score) arrays/tuples).

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of redis (>= v6.2.0), if you want to get all members of a sorted set between two scores, you should use:

```
ZRANGE key min max BYSCORE
```

Adding the `BYSCORE` option makes redis treat the `min` & `max` arguments as scores rather than indices.

(As of this writing, `ZRANGEBYSCORE` still works, but is considered deprecated.)